# laravel 7 eye hidden

Tags: php, laravel

i try to add hide eye in password in laravel project in register. i find code in codepen but when i add

`<span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>`

Register

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12">
            
                <h1 style="border-bottom: solid yellow;"><strong>Formulaire d'inscription</strong></h1>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                    <h3><strong>Vos identifiants</strong></h3>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Adresse mail</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Mot de passe</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                
                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Confirmation mot de passe</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <h3><strong>Informations personnelles</strong></h3>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="sex" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Civilité</label>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexe" id="exampleRadios1" value="M" checked>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                        Male
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexe" id="exampleRadios2" value="F">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                                        Female
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Prénom</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="firstname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nom</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control @error('firstname') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname" value="{{ old('firstname') }}" required autocomplete="firstname" autofocus>

                                @error('firstname')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Adresse</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control @error('address') is-invalid @enderror" name="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required autocomplete="address" autofocus>

                                @error('address')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="city" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Ville</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="city" type="text" class="form-control @error('city') is-invalid @enderror" name="city" value="{{ old('city') }}" required autocomplete="city" autofocus>

                                @error('city')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="zipcode" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Code postale</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="zipcode" type="text" class="form-control @error('zipcode') is-invalid @enderror" name="zipcode" value="{{ old('zipcode') }}" required autocomplete="zipcode" autofocus>

                                @error('zipcode')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Numéro de téléphone</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required autocomplete="phone" autofocus>

                                @error('phone')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="birthday" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Date de naissance</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="birthday" type="date" class="form-control @error('birthday') is-invalid @enderror" name="birthday" value="{{ old('birthday') }}" required autocomplete="birthday" autofocus>

                                @error('birthday')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="pseudo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nom d'utilisateur (pseudo)</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="pseudo" type="text" class="form-control @error('pseudo') is-invalid @enderror" name="pseudo" value="{{ old('pseudo') }}" required autocomplete="pseudo" autofocus>

                                @error('pseudo')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="avatar" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="avatar" type="file" class="form-control @error('avatar') is-invalid @enderror" name="avatar"  autocomplete="avatar" autofocus>

                                @error('avatar')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-4">
                                <div class="g-recaptcha" 
                                        data-sitekey="{{env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY')}}">
                                </div>
                                <span role="alert" class="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                    @error('g-recaptcha-response')
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</strong>
                                    @enderror
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Crée mon compte
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show_hide_password a").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#show_hide_password input').attr("type") == "text"){
            $('#show_hide_password input').attr('type', 'password');
            $('#show_hide_password i').addClass( "fa-eye-slash" );
            $('#show_hide_password i').removeClass( "fa-eye" );
        }else if($('#show_hide_password input').attr("type") == "password"){
            $('#show_hide_password input').attr('type', 'text');
            $('#show_hide_password i').removeClass( "fa-eye-slash" );
            $('#show_hide_password i').addClass( "fa-eye" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
@endsection


@section('scripts')
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

@endsection
```

not have something, i try to add code from there :
https://codepen.io/Qanser/pen/dVRGJvm but its not work for me i think i do something not good someone can help me add eye? Nothing appears, it's been 2 hours already I'm on it I can't take it anymore XD Someone
you can see my screen shot in this link : ibb.co/W2kQTj8
Have mercy on a noob help me XD

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little bit ? I tried to click on your codepen.io link but there is an eye and it's worked. What are you trying to say?

Comment: you can see my screen shot in this link : https://ibb.co/W2kQTj8

Comment: And code of register i added

Comment: Have you checked in your current DOM to determine whether the block `<div class="input-group-addon"> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>` is existed or not ?

Comment: If existed I think you can check directly that block's current CSS and find out what is happening there. If not, maybe you forgot to add `@endif` to close the if condition somewhere

Comment: i dont understand what i need to do? where is it it's DOM i'm noob :/ just begin with laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that the page layouts.app that you extend have the link to fa eye class like one bellow

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: open the layouts.app page in your laravel directory and in head tag copy the link tag in the  above code snippet to yours and test it again

Comment: You are its the best, last question, how do I enter it inside the password field?

Comment: did you find the layouts.app page??

Comment: yes it's worked, for this i talk you are the best =) but i try to do like this codepen.io/Qanser/pen/dVRGJv but there is no gray field with the eye next to the field where you have to write the password. there is a little blue eye, you know where this error comes from? my show hidden it's like in this screenshot xD zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/29/kwge.png

Comment: you want to know in javascript there are selectors which are html elements IDs or classes so you can make this functionality. you have #show_hide_password in your script which is not exist in your html this is the reason